# Pass command-line arguments to Startup class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, owin, katana

I have arguments passed in via the command-line

```
private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    const string PORT = "12345"    ;

    var listeningUrl = $"http://localhost:{PORT}";

    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls(listeningUrl);

    var host = builder.Build();
    WriteLine($"Running on {PORT}");
    host.Run();

    return 0;
}
```

One of these arguments is a logging output directory. How do I get this value into my `Startup` class so I can write out to this directory when I receive a request?

I'd like to avoid using a static class. Would a service that supplies the value be the right way?  If so, how do I get services injected into my middleware?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should be able to use the `AddCommandLine()` extension. First install the Nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` and ensure you have the correct import:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Now update your `Main` method to include the new config:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true) //this is not needed, but could be useful
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)  //<-- Add this
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseUrls(listeningUrl);
```

Now you treat the command line options as configuration:

```
dotnet run /MySetting:SomeValue=123
```

And read in code:

```
var someValue = Configuration.GetValue<int>("MySetting:SomeValue");
```

Comment: Great!  Do you know what Nuget package it live in?

Comment: Aye, sounds reasonable but it's not in there.

Comment: I've got that, got a `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine;` at the top but still no `AddCommandLine` method.

Comment: Package manager claims it is `1.1.2`:  `Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 1.1.2'`

Comment: I actually have both.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep having a poke about, might be a VS caching something type thing.

Comment: Oh hang on, I was slightly wrong, look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting#overriding-configuration

Comment: Is `Configuration` here a property on the `Startup` class?  I can't find it in any assemblies.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you already had that. You need to inject it. Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Comment: The eamples on here have the configuration being build in the `Startup` class rather than the `Program`.

Comment: This function doesn't exist for me even with the package installed. I have Host.CreateDefaultBuilder() method

Comment: Does that also work for command line flags, like `--debug` or `--verbose`? If so, how?

Comment: Regarding to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` use the `ConfigureHostConfiguration` method in order to create the configuration builder.

Answer (score 26):

**Dotnet Core 2**

You don't need most of the code as in dotnet core 1.0 to achieve this. 
`AddCommandLine`arguments are automatically injected when you BuildWebHost using the following syntax

Step 1.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .Build();
}
```

Step 2. Inject configurations to Startup.cs using DI using the following code

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    ...

}
```

Step 3. Access your arguments using configurations object.

```
var seed = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("seed");
Console.WriteLine($"seed: {seed}");
```

Step 4. Start application with arguments

```
dotnet run seed=True
```

Answer (score 12):

ASP.NET Core 2 answer:

Change the default Program.cs to be:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

I removed other bits just to make the configuration explanation easier.

**Note the `.AddCommandLine(args)` line in the configuration builder.**

Unlike @BanksySan's answer you DON'T need to create a static property, instead let DI inject the IConfiguration into the startup class.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

You can now use the configuration entries from any of the config providers, file, env variables **and commandline**.

Example:

dotnet run --seed true

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        var seed = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("seed");
        if (seed)
            SeedData.Initialize(app);

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Hope this helps someone further.

Comment: I was able to do the same thing on my Worker.cs class too for when hosting ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service - adding a constructor that takes in the IConfiguration object worked there too.

Answer (score 6):

[DavidG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45220246/442351) is correct, but there were still some pieces of the puzzle missing for me.

There are two Nuget packages you need:

1. `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`
2. `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine`

Because we want the command line arguments, we need to create the configuration in the `Main(string[])`.

```csharp
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

class Program
{
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string PORT = "12345";

        var listeningUrl = $"http://localhost:{PORT}";
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .AddCommandLine(args)
                            .Build();
        // Set the `static` `Configuration` property on the `Startup` class.
        Startup.Configuration = configuration;

        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseSetting("Message", "Hello World")
            .UseUrls(listeningUrl);

        var host = builder.Build();
        WriteLine($"Running on {listeningUrl}");
        host.Run();

        return SUCCESS_EXIT_CODE;
    }
}
```

The `Startup` class is:

```csharp
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class Startup
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        foreach (var c in Configuration.AsEnumerable())
            Console.WriteLine($"{c.Key,-15}:{c.Value}");
    }
}
```

Is the command argument are `--port 6000 outputDirectory C:\Temp` then this will output:

```
port            :6000
outputDirectory :C:\Temp
```

Comment: Also in Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration#setup-and-use-the-commandline-configuration-provider

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the raw command line arguments passed to the process, or you don't want to add them to the configuration, you can still use the following:

```cs
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```