# Which the string values does expect the` CreateDefaultBuilder` method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1

In the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.0) I see `CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)` method. But I don't see any examples its using. Which arguments are expected by the method at this case? I can pass such args: `"Hello", "World"` but this is unlikely to be what was expected by the method...

Comment: documentations states `args: The command line args.`

Comment: @Nkosi I've read it before I created the topic. This information does not help me.

Comment: [This article might help](http://www.koderdojo.com/blog/set-host-environment-in-asp-net-core-using-command-line-arguments)

Comment: The following article should also help

[ASP.NET Core – passing command-line arguments to Startup class](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2018/01/16/asp-net-core-passing-command-line-arguments-startup-class/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line arguments are usually used to pass some configuration information to the program when executing it.

A typical program calls `CreateDefaultBuilder` to start setting up a host.

Any configuration loaded may be overridden by command-line arguments.

For example, the following was taken directly from documentation with some or my own wording

Assuming a *`hosting.json`* file like this

```
{
    urls: "http://*:5005"
}
```

Overriding the configuration provided by `UseUrls` with *hosting.json* config first, command-line argument config second:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args) //<--
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000") //<--
            .UseConfiguration(config) //<--
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                app.Run(context => 
                    context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, World!"));
            })
            .Build();
    }
}
```

To specify the host run on a particular URL, the desired value can be passed in from a command prompt when executing `dotnet run`. The command-line argument overrides the urls value from the hosting.json file, and the server listens on port 8080:

```
dotnet run --urls "http://*:8080"
```

Reference [Hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

The following article should also help

[ASP.NET Core – passing command-line arguments to Startup class](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2018/01/16/asp-net-core-passing-command-line-arguments-startup-class/)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use it for initializing of *the custom nested settings* are saved in the `appsettings.json` file? For example, can I reset the `stuff` value of such configuration: `{"foo":{"stuff":true}}`?

Comment: @AndreyBushman yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219949/pass-command-line-arguments-to-startup-class-in-asp-core