# Pass argument to main method when using MVC Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Say I have some code like this from an ASP.NET MVC Core app:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity";

    var seed = args.Any(x => x == "/seed");
    if (seed) args = args.Except(new[] { "/seed" }).ToArray();

    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    if (seed)
    {
        SeedData.EnsureSeedData(host.Services);
        return;
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

How do I pass an arguement of "/seed" to this method (to seed the data)? So far I have tried:

1) This:

[image]

No arguement is passed to Main.

2) Looked here (amongst other places):

[Pass command-line arguments to Startup class in ASP Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219949/pass-command-line-arguments-to-startup-class-in-asp-core)

Comment: @Liam this is about using the command line parameters in configuration. The OP is asking why there are no parameters to begin with. Not suprising, since the web site is *not* launched from the command line

Comment: @w0051977 you are launching IIS Express, not the application. Your debug settings say "Launch IIS Express with `/seed` as an argument"

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, main is definitely called when I start debugging in Visual Studio - I added a breakpoint to check.

Comment: @w0051977 yes, but you are passing the arguments to IIS, not the application. You are launching IIS Express, which then launches the application. Have you tried changing the `Launch` setting?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, many thanks that was it.  Changing "Launch" to "Project" solved it.  Please post an answer so that I can give credit.  +1 for: "you are launching IIS Express, not the application"

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the argument into quotation marks like "/seed"

[image: Project properties]

[image: Runtime]